# IllegalArgumentException: Bad stream type 21

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I got sometimes following exception on the playStore. It occures on different devices and also on different Android Versions. I never had such an error during testing and I can't produce that error. What could be the problem with the getStreamVolume?

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad stream type 21
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1326)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1276)
at android.media.IAudioService$Stub$Proxy.getStreamVolume(IAudioService.java:508)
at android.media.AudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.java:487)
at de.free.Activity.startStopService(Activity.java:452)
at de.free.Activity.onClick(Activity.java:409)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2506)
at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:99)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9112)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thats the code from the Method startStopService:

```
private void startStopService() {
    long now = new Date().getTime();

    Intent i = new Intent(this, AppService.class);

    i.putExtra(AppService.VOLUME, volumeBar.getProgress());
    i.putExtra(AppService.RINGER, amanager.getRingerMode());
    i.putExtra(AppService.ACT_VOL, amanager.getStreamVolume(amanager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING)));
    i.putExtra(AppService.VOL_ALM, amanager.getStreamVolume(amanager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM)));
    i.putExtra(AppService.TIME_NOW, now);

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);   

    if((tb_runBG.isChecked())) {        
        alarmManager.cancel(pi);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 *update_time, pi);    
    } else {
        alarmManager.cancel(pi);
        stopService(new Intent(this, AppService.class));    
    }
}
```

AudioManager at onCreate:

```
//sets the range between 0 and the max volume
volumeBar.setMax(amanager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING));
```

Comment: Which devices are affected by this? Can you name one or two? Are they all from the same vendor?

Comment: At the moment ist just Samsung, I found following to this issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=70783

Comment: Can I fix it by just put in a try catch surrounding amanager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING) and amanager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM) and for these just use default parameters? Or occurs it by just accessing it?

Comment: The last message of a user was that the App crashes and he has to restart the phone. He uses a Samsung S6 edge with Android 5.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think its a Hardware Problem, put your code in a try/catch code

```
try{
    //sets the range between 0 and the max volume
    volumeBar.setMax(amanager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING));
 }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){}
```

check [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=70783)

AFAIK - to prevent a crash on your side, as for device restarting that is not your side, so im sorry you can not take care of that, the error is being shifted to Samsung and lG-(Manufacturers).  so yeah the device might restart when it should, atleast you will convince the user that its not your fault by putting a try/catch block, but if not the user will put the blame on you, as all started when your app crashed. if you read the post actually the solution was to put a try/catch block or return 0 or anything, so i think that is your best bet.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I also thing its a Hardware problem. But getStreamVolume is the problem. If I surround getStreamVolume with try/catch I think I don't getting an error in my App anymore but does the Phone need to be restarted? If just accessing it is the problem I'm not allowed to access getStreamVolume. Is it solved with try/catch?

Comment: I will put on every getStreamVolume a try / catch and hopefully everything is ok.